# Scala: Enforce compile error on type alias mismatch

Tags: scala, settings, type-alias

Is there a way to get compile time error (or at least warning) when assigning different type aliases that share the same underlying type?

In other words, say I have this code:

```
type Address = String
type City = String

def foo(x:Address) = ...
```

I want to get a compile time error/warning if I do:

```
val city: City = "Dublin"
foo(city)
```

As far as I can tell, the compiler allows it because they are the same underlying type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to get this "type-safety" you seek for type aliases. However, there is an alternative to type aliases that can be used for what you desire: [**Value Classes**](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). Basically, a value class can give you a type without allocating a new object. Note that there are some limitations to value classes that you do not have for type aliases.

To quote the scala documentation:

> **Correctness**
>
> Another use case for value classes is to get the type safety of a data type without the runtime allocation overhead. For example, a fragment of a data type that represents a distance might look like:

```
  class Meter(val value: Double) extends AnyVal {
    def +(m: Meter): Meter = new Meter(value + m.value)
  }
```

> Code that adds two distances, such as

```
  val x = new Meter(3.4)
  val y = new Meter(4.3)
  val z = x + y
```

> will not actually allocate any Meter instances, but will only use primitive doubles at runtime.

Comment: Can I make value case classes? I kinda dislike the new keyword usage

Comment: You can define value case classes. By the way: The reason you can omitt the `new`-keyword is the (generated) companion-object's `apply`-method, so you do not necessarily need to define a case class to get rid of the keyword.

Comment: Yes I know, I just prefer not defining my own companions for all the type aliases, it's long and dull ^_^

Answer (score 3):

No. At least, not without modifying the compiler (it *might* be possible with a compiler plugin, or even a macro), and if you made this change then a lot of popular libraries (including the standard library) and standard code examples would not compile.

You might like to use value classes, as described in @Kulu's answer. Alternatively, [Scalaz Tagged Types](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html) avoid overhead in more situations (e.g. putting them in a collection, or using `subst` to safely upcast a generic type that uses a tagged type).